# Cannot find function getMessage in object GmailMessage

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I cant get the message ID of the email sent using this code.

```
function getEmailDetails(){

var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; // Get first thread in inbox
var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; // Get first message
var id = message.getId();
var messageById = GmailApp.getMessageById(id);
Logger.log(message.getSubject() == messageById.getMessage()); 

};
```

Answer (score 2):

[`GmailApp.getMessageById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getmessagebyidid) returns a [GmailMessage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message.html). So you can't call `getMessage()` because your variable `messageById` is already a GmailMessage and that method doesn't exist in the object.

In your Logger statement, you also can't effectively compare `message.getSubject()` with a GmailMessage because [`.getSubject()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getsubject) returns a string. You can't accurately compare a string with a GmailMessage object.